# polynomial which is zero for all values, has to have zero coeficients

Tags: polynomials

Let $k$ be an infinite field. and define the polynomial in $f \in k[x]$ to be

$f= a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + ... + a_1 x$

If for all $x \in k$, we have $f=0$, then all $a_i$ have to be zero.

Could someone please help me to prove it? and also why being infinite is important here?

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of the factor theorem, which states that a polynomial $f$ over a field $k$ has zero at $a \in k$ if and only if $x-a$ is a factor of $f$.

If $f$ is nonconstant then it has degree $m$ for some $m > 0$ and at most $m$ roots up to multiplicity, so the only way for $f$ to have infinitely many roots is for it to be identically zero.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just another question: being infinite is sufficient or necessary condition here?

Comment: I mean what is a counter example for finite field?

Comment: Try constructing one! (Hint: say with $k = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and look for a quadratic.)